# socket.io reconnect example

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

the socket.io docs says we should implement our own reconnect?

Does anyone have an example of a simple reconnect scheme?

The idea is that if the user reconnects within 20 seconds he should be given the same socket.io sessionid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

socket.io has [reconnect support](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io) now, using the options `reconnect` and `reconnectionDelay` so you can let that handle everything for you if you need.

Comment: are you sure this gives the same sessionid?